# How to unroll template specializations

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, types, variadic-templates

I am trying to get the type at the specified index in a parameter pack using template metaprogramming.  I have the code below but for some reason it always returns an `int`,  could someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;

template <int current_index, typename... Vs>
struct TypeForIndex {};
template <int current_index, typename Head, typename... Tail>
struct TypeForIndex<current_index, Head, Tail...> : private TypeForIndex<current_index + 1> {
    using type = Head;
};
template <int current_index, typename Tail>
struct TypeForIndex<current_index, Tail> {
    using type = Tail;
};

int main() {

    TypeForIndex <2, int, double, string>::type a {"hello"};
    cout << a << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The code above should return `string` as the type for `a` but somehow it is always an `int`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
TypeForIndex<2, int, double, string>
```

ok, pattern matching time.  First, it clearly matches

```
template <int current_index, typename... Vs>
struct TypeForIndex {};
```

so no error.  Does it match any other specializations?

A:

```
template <int current_index, typename Head, typename... Tail>
struct TypeForIndex<current_index, Head, Tail...>
```

B:

```
template <int current_index, typename Tail>
struct TypeForIndex<current_index, Tail>
```

Well, it matches (A) and not (B).

With (A), `current_index` is `2`, `Head` is `int` and `Tail...` is `double, std::string`.

```
template <int current_index, typename Head, typename... Tail>
struct TypeForIndex<current_index, Head, Tail...> : private TypeForIndex<current_index + 1> {
    using type = Head;
};
```

Now, the `private TypeForIndex<current_index + 1>` is pretty much useless.  It always only matches the primary specialization, which has an empty body, and it is private so nobody will notice it.  We can remove it without changing your program's behavior at all.

```
template <int current_index, typename Head, typename... Tail>
struct TypeForIndex<current_index, Head, Tail...> {
    using type = Head;
};
```

As noted above, `Head` is `int`.  So we get `type=int`.

And that's it.  That is why `type` is `int`.

...

What you are doing wrong is almost everything?  Other than compiling (ie, the primary specialization exists that matches the signature), the code you provide has nothing to do with what you describe in your text.  Even `current_index+1` is a string I wouldn't expect to exist in code that does what your text describes.

Throwing out everything except the primary specialization, this works:

```
template <typename Head, typename... Tail>
struct TypeForIndex<0, Head, Tail...> {
  using type = Head;
};
template <int current_index, typename Head, typename... Tail>
struct TypeForIndex<current_index, Head, Tail...>:
  TypeForIndex<current_index-1, Tail...>
{};
```

and it properly lacks a definition for `type` if you pass a too-large index.

I would also use a `size_t` not an `int`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's your fix.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;

template <int current_index, typename... Vs>
struct TypeForIndex {};

template <int current_index, typename Head, typename... Tail>
struct TypeForIndex<current_index, Head, Tail...> : TypeForIndex<current_index - 1, Tail...> {};

template <typename Head, typename... Tail>
struct TypeForIndex<0, Head, Tail...> {
    using type = Head;
};

int main() {
    TypeForIndex <2, int, double, string, char>::type a ("hello");
    cout << a << endl;
}
```

Comment: The above is only a fix insofar as replacing `TypeForIndex<2,int,double,string>::type` with `string` is a fix: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d2876707b8677e26 -- it returns the right type, but is not correct.  In the link, I added a `char` type to the end of the pack, and your code fails to compile.

Comment: Yes.  I was just editing his code until it compiled.  I didn't realize he had even more mistakes.  I added the missing `Tail...` to the code.

Comment: @prestokeys Thank you for your answer!  Yours made just as much sense to me but I am going to go ahead and accept Yakk's answer just because it has a better explanation. I upvoted you with the 15 points though!